# Error, failed to compile when running ng serve using ng-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I just started with ng cli & Angular. Did my first project setup.
The command `ng serve` fails to run with below error. Launching the application using `http://localhost:4200/` shows empty screen with message `Cannot GET /`

What does this mean ? How to resolve this problem ?

> ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,44): error
>   TS1005: ';' expected. node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,74):
>   error TS1005: ';' expected.
>   node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,77): error TS1109: Expression
>   expected.

Comment: what is your rxjs version and angular version? What is the error in browser console?

Comment: angular - 6.1.0, rxjs - 6.0.0. These versions are kept unchanged from the files prepped by angular cli.

Comment: Try running npm start, ng build and then ng serve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your project.json file.

If you have something like ^ in "rxjs": "^6.0.0" from package.json and make it "rxjs": "6.0.0" and it should work fine.